# Throttle CPU based on Temperature? - Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I was running some programs on my Ubuntu machine that use max CPU power for extended periods of time. This causes the computer to overheat.

Could someone suggest a good program that will throttle CPU power down to maintain a set temperature?

I tried Jupiter but it does not have that feature. I also tried some Linux scripts but I do not have the skills to modify them to work on Ubuntu.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I agree that this belongs on super user or askubuntu. In fact here is a similar question posted on askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/171397/limit-cpu-usage-in-terms-of-temperature

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. I have cleaned out the computer and have extra fans working on it. It normally runs around 60c which I think is good. However, when I run programs that use max CPU power for a very long time it can get up to 90c and then I turn off the programs as its too hot. In my experience when I leave it up to the computer to save itself when it gets too hot it just shuts down. I would preferr that it scale back the CPU so the work can continue as it heats up fairly fast. I was hoping there would be some kind of script that I could run that would take care of that for me.

Comment: The shut down temperature is most likely not at 90c but higher.

Answer (score 20):

This is normally dealt with quite well by the CPU [governor](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt) and the kernel itself. The CPU should be throttled automatically as soon as dangerous temperatures are reached. What makes you think it is a problem? What temperatures are you running at?

Anyway, here are a couple of things you might want to try.

1. Play with the different [governors](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt). Most modern systems scale the CPU frequency according to the current need. On Linux systems, this is controlled by the "cpu governor", if all you want is to run the job without heating up and don't care about speed, set the governor to "Powersave"

   ```
   sudo -i
   echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
   ```

   You can check which governor is set with this command:

   ```
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
   ```

   Available options are:

   - performance
   - powersave
   - userspace
   - ondemand
   - conservative
2. Use `cpufreq` to manually set the speed of your processor:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
   ```

   Find the available processor speeds (the examples are from my laptop):

   ```
   LC_ALL=C cpufreq-info | grep "available frequency"
   available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
   ```

   Now set a low frequency (for example, 1.20 GHz):

   ```
   sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.20
   ```
3. If you *still* think it is necessary, you can make a script that monitors the temperature and sets the frequency on demand. However, this is bound to be worse than letting the kernel handle it and depends on `sensors` or `acpi` or similar being correctly configured and is really not worth it.

Comment: @rubo77 Newer Intel CPUs [only support](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM3NDQ) the "powersave" and "performance" governors. Since the "userspace" governor is needed to set the frequency (according to your man page) that won't be possible for these machines.

Comment: I don't have a line "available frequency" in my output on an intel i5-8265U. only "hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.90 GHz". maybe you can set the maximum frequency on those?

Answer (score -1):

Why not first think about the location and the environment of the computer?

Is it able to have good air circulation?

Is the room cool? Perhaps air conditioning or open the window?

Have you took the back off and used a Hoover to remove any collected dust?

Comment: yes... the environment is good. any script running at max cpu speed will eventually overheat the computer. a script is needed to reduce cpu speed to slow the script down and cool the computer.